# Restoring an Oracle database from files

Tags: oracle

I am running into a problem now, i have an oracle database that is stored inside a server and now because of the sudden blackout the c drive is messed up. The drive is partitioned, windows on c and oracle on drive e.

The oracle installation folder is fine on E:\app. Now i have to restore that database on the another server to get it running. The problem is i cant boot windows on that drive.

Anybody can help me on restoring the database from oracle installation folder ? I know i cant run rman because rman can only be run from command line only which i cant run it now.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you would want to install a new instance somewhere—possibly on the same host.

Then you would need to mount the control file (the path to the control file can be specified by setting the `control_files` parameter value in pfile).

Once you've mounted the control file with `alter database mount`, you can use RMAN to identify the data (temp, undo) files' location with `report schema` command.

You would also need to identify the undo files' location. Use `V$LOGFILE` view.

If you want to move the files around before opening the database, use `RENAME FILE .. TO ..` clause of the `ALTER DATABASE` statement.

When you're done with all these tasks, you can try to open the database.

```
SQL> alter database open;
```

See also.

- [Redo Log Data Dictionary Views](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo009.htm)
- [Renaming and Relocating Datafiles](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles005.htm)
- [Relocating and Renaming Redo Log Members](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo004.htm)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32648/discussion-between-konz-mama-and-yasir-arsanukaev).